# Opentok livestreaming broadcast request error

Tags: opentok, tokbox

When I make a request to start live streaming broadcast to opentok api, 
I have this error :

```
{
  "message" : "session cannot be broadcasted when mantis not available. with code 400"
}
```

In below my request term with postman :

#### url request

https://api.opentok.com/v2/project/api_key/broadcast

#### header parameters

X-OPENTOK-AUTH : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...

Accept : application/json

Content-Type : application/json

EDIT : 
This query is run in the following context: a session with two stream published. The API key is present as well as the session id.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Based on the error message, it looks like you're trying to start a broadcast with a session that's set to `relayed` mode. You must set the [`mediaMode`](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-session/#media-mode) to `routed` when creating a session so you can leverage OpenTok's media servers and use the broadcast feature.

Comment: That's right, thanks ! I had completely forgotten media mode setting...
but what is mantis?

Comment: That's internal stuff, no need to worry about that.

Comment: Thank you for responding to this SO post! But.. this is a really bad error message, especially when 409 according to API doc means that the broadcast has already been started :)

Comment: Yes, agreed! I've filed this issue internally :)

Answer (score 0):

Tokbox QA staff here.

You have to put your API Key in the request.

Assuming you're doing it, you cannot do that request like that. First of all, you must create a session, and then, start a broadcast on that session, providing some info inside the POST body:

https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#start_broadcast

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I make all that, I removed my api key for not being seen. And I did the query with 2 publisher.

Comment: can you show here the request you're using to start the broadcast? headers and body as well

Comment: Are you using routed or relayed mediaMode for the session? You cannot broadcast a relayed session.